# Derivative of Function with Cases

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have been trying to solve a problem, and wish to clarify some slight worry I have that my approach is flawed. I don't think it's necessary to include the particular function I am considering, since it's a fairly contrived question and I am more curious about whether I am doing the correct thing *in general*.

Suppose I have some function such that

$G(x) = \begin{cases}f(x)&x\not=a\\0 &x=a.\end{cases}$

If I am given that $f$ is differentiable for $x\not=a$, do I automatically know then that $G(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$. I believe this is true. Then if I wished to calculate the derivative at $x=a$, then I would proceed as follows:

$$G'(a)= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{G(x)-G(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-0}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}.$$

Then in a particular case, we calculate whatever this limit may be. Is this approach correct?

Am I right to not just piecewise differentiate the function $G(x)$, i.e not to write
$G'(x) = \begin{cases}f'(x)&x\not=a\\0 &x=a.\end{cases}$ and then to say $G'(a)=0$, or is this the correct approach and I am misunderstanding the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not automatically know that $G$ is differentiable at $x=a$. You don't even automatically know whether $G$ is continuous at $x=a$.

You are right that 
$$
G'(a)= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{G(x)-G(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-0}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}
$$
but not that 
$$
G'(x) = \begin{cases}f'(x)&x\not=a\\0 &x=a.\end{cases}
$$

For example, with $f(x) = x + x^2\sin \frac1x$ you get
$$
G'(x) = \begin{cases}f'(x)&x\not=a\\1 &x=a.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was given that $G$ is differentiable in the question, but had to prove it. So thanks for highlighting where I need to fix my argument. So indeed, if I know that it is differentiable, I should go down the difference quotient route to get $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}$, right?

Comment: In fact: is it actually the way to show that the function G is differentiable, by showing that the limit of the difference quotient at $a$ exists, rather than trying to prove separately that G is differentiable and then find whatever its derivative is?

Comment: That is correct. If that limit exists then $G$ is differentiable and thus automatically also continuous at $x=a$.

Answer (score 1):

To say thay $G(x)$ is differentiable at $a$, then it must be continuous at $a$ in the first place.

So how about, $G(x)= \begin{cases}|x| &x\not=0 \\0 &x=0.\end{cases}$?

$f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable for $x\ne 0$ but is $G(x)$ differentiable at $0$ ?